# How can I find out my forgotten account password

Tags: support, password

I have account on Stack Overflow. I am logged in currently, but I don't remember my password. So I cannot enter my account from another PC, and if cookies become lost, I cannot to enter Stack Overflow on my account at all.

How can I find out what is the password to my account (I am currently logged in and can see all of my account data)?

Comment: Are you using the StackExchange OpenID provider? Otherwise your password is the issue of whichever OpenID provider you have chosen to use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the password is stored hashed on the database, so even the site's owner cannot retrieve it.
Try changing it using Tech4Wilco's link, you can't find out what the old one was.

Comment: Since SE uses OpenID, it doesn't store users' passwords in its database, hashed or otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to use: https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

Comment: But in email I can only see my Email.
How can I find out my password?

Comment: @DullDrifter It's common security practice to never store the actual plain text password on the server